# Migrating Rails app with ActiveAdmin to NodeJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby, mongodb, postgresql

I'm migrating an app made by another developer in Ruby on Rails to NodeJS, the app has an ActiveAdmin to handle some operations and check some stats, I wanted to know what similar tool/framework can I use in Node to do the migration as less painful as possible.

Also, apart from this question I wanted to ask about using Node PostgreSQL implementation vs migrating to Mongo (I know that without seeing the code is not easy to answer, but I'm looking for insights, like: Postgres has not much contributors in Node, better migrate to Mongo)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you migrating from rails to NodeJs?